# Plotting coordinates with vectors on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, coordinates

I have two vectors `x` and `y`.

I want to plot them both as coordinates, ex: `(x1,y1) ; (x2,y2)`, with a dot representing each point. I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried to use the use the `meshgrid` function but it didn't work out.

Comment: I think it would help if you could clarify if you want to plot lines between points (eg  `(x1(1), y1(1)) ->(x2(1), y2(1))`, `(x1(2),y1(2)) -> ((x2(2), y2(2))`...) or instead you want to plot two sets of points (in which case, you need the scatter plot, probably as described in @SulfoCyaNate's answer)

Comment: i wanst clear enough, although @SulfoCyaNate's could help me through, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to plot them as vectors from the origin, MATLAB's `plotv` function (which comes with the Neural Network toolbox) allows you to do just that.

The following should work:

```
M = [x1 x2 ; ...
     y1 y2];
plotv(M)
```

You can find the documentation at the [MATLAB plotv page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/plotv.html).

If, however, you wish to plot only the points, you may use a scatter plot. You could use the following:

```
X = [x1 x2];
Y = [y1 y2];
scatter(X, Y)
```

The documentation of the scatter plot may be found at the [MATLAB scatter page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html).

If you intend to plot a vector from (x1, y1) to (x2, y2), the following, using MATLAB's `quiver` function, should help:

```
quiver(x1,y1,(x2 - x1),(y2 - y1),0)
```

Please find the documentation for `quiver` on [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html). In the example I discussed, the `0` is for turning off automatic scaling.

Comment: Note that `plotv` is part of the Neural Network toolbox, so it's not available in standard MATLAB installations. `scatter` will work though =)

Comment: the second thing is exactly what i wanted to do, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at Paul Mennen's `plt` package on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4936-plt).

This includes an auxillary function `Pquiv` (documented [here](http://www.mennen.org/plt/pltfiles/Programming%20with%20plt/Auxiliary%20functions.htm)) that allows the plotting of vectors.

An example picture is at [this](http://www.mennen.org/plt/pltfiles/demoImages/pltquiv.png) location, with the source code available for that plot as one of the 'demo' files.

The documentation for this project is very good, and although I'm still trying to get used to the setup, it does help with a lot of plotting related issues in Matlab.

The author (email address available after installation by using `help plt`) is also quick to respond to questions that people have, some of which are also visible in the comments on File Exchange.

Comment: What does this do that `quiver` doesn't?

Comment: A notable (at least for me) feature of `plt` is the `threadId` panel, which allows the selection/removal of a given plot. Tools are generated to allow switching log/linear plots and some of the built-in matlab `uicontrol`s have 'improved' alternatives (eg slider bar, although for my case I stuck with the Matlab version).

Answer (score 0):

Why this didn't work?

> plot(x,y,'o','MarkerFaceColor','b'); axis square; hold on

best

Comment: No need for `MarkerFaceColor`, just do `plot(x,y,'bo')`. Also, `axis square` and `hold on` don't relate to this particular question.

Comment: Well, granted. But it doesn't hurt to have some good taste in one's plots, doesn't it? :)